# pandas: given a start and end date, add a column for each day in between, then add values?

Tags: python, pandas

This is my data:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([
   {start_date: '2019/12/01', end_date: '2019/12/05', spend: 10000, campaign_id: 1}
   {start_date: '2019/12/05', end_date: '2019/12/09', spend: 50000, campaign_id: 2}
   {start_date: '2019/12/01', end_date: '', spend: 10000, campaign_id: 3}
   {start_date: '2019/12/01', end_date: '2019/12/01', spend: 50, campaign_id: 4}
]);
```

I need to add a column to each row for each day since 2019/12/01, and calculate the spend on that campaign that day, which I'll get by dividing the spend on the campaign by the total number of days it was active.

So here I'd add a column for each day between 1 December and today (10 December). For row 1, the content of the five columns for 1 Dec to 5 Dec would be 2000, then for the six ocolumns from 5 Dec to 10 Dec it would be zero.

I know pandas is well-designed for this kind of problem, but I have no idea where to start!

Comment: How would you handle the missing `end_date` in the third row?

Comment: can you give an expected output

Comment: @AdibP sorry should have specified that - should be set to today's date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doesn't seem like a straight forward task to me. But first convert your date columns if you haven't already:

```
df["start_date"] = pd.to_datetime(df["start_date"])
df["end_date"] = pd.to_datetime(df["end_date"])
```

Then create a helper function for resampling:

```
def resampler(data, daterange):
    temp = (data.set_index('start_date').groupby('campaign_id')
                 .apply(daterange)
                 .drop("campaign_id",axis=1)
                 .reset_index().rename(columns={"level_1":"start_date"}))
    return temp
```

Now its a 3 step process. First resample your data according to `end_date` of each group:

```
df1 = resampler(df, lambda d: d.reindex(pd.date_range(min(d.index),max(d["end_date"]),freq="D")) if d["end_date"].notnull().all() else d)

df1["spend"] = df1.groupby("campaign_id")["spend"].transform(lambda x: x.mean()/len(x))
```

With the average values calculated, `resample` again to current date:

```
dates = pd.date_range(min(df["start_date"]),pd.Timestamp.today(),freq="D")

df1 = resampler(df1,lambda d: d.reindex(dates))
```

Finally transpose your dataframe:

```
df1 = pd.concat([df1.drop("end_date",axis=1).set_index(["campaign_id","start_date"]).unstack(),
                 df1.groupby("campaign_id")["end_date"].min()], axis=1)
df1.columns = [*dates,"end_date"]

print (df1)

#
             2019-12-01 00:00:00  2019-12-02 00:00:00  2019-12-03 00:00:00  2019-12-04 00:00:00  2019-12-05 00:00:00  2019-12-06 00:00:00  2019-12-07 00:00:00  2019-12-08 00:00:00  2019-12-09 00:00:00  2019-12-10 00:00:00   end_date
campaign_id                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
1                         2000.0               2000.0               2000.0               2000.0               2000.0                  NaN                  NaN                  NaN                  NaN                  NaN 2019-12-05
2                            NaN                  NaN                  NaN                  NaN              10000.0              10000.0              10000.0              10000.0              10000.0                  NaN 2019-12-09
3                        10000.0                  NaN                  NaN                  NaN                  NaN                  NaN                  NaN                  NaN                  NaN                  NaN        NaT
4                           50.0                  NaN                  NaN                  NaN                  NaN                  NaN                  NaN                  NaN                  NaN                  NaN 2019-12-01
```